# Liferay webform portlet field validation

Tags: javascript, webforms, validation, liferay

Portlet describes how should it work:

> Enter JavaScript code that returns true or false to validate the
>   field. The following implicit variables are available.
>
> currentFieldValue: The value being validated fieldsMap: The array of
>   all form values indexed by name

I haven't found any documentation about this.

Anyways, I have web form that send the form input to my email, but if the last checkbox is not checked then it should give an error.

So I came up with this code, but it doesn't work:

```
if(currentFieldValue == false){return false;}
```

Anybody knows how this liferay webform portlet validation works?

Answer (score 0):

1. Stop Tomcat
2. Go to APPLICATION_SERVER_ROOT_DIRECTORY/webapps/web-form-portlet/WEB-INF/classes directory
3. Open portlet.properties and change "validation.script.enabled" property from "false" to "true"
4. Start Tomcat
5. Add **Web Form** portlet to a page
6. On the configuration pop-up of Web Form portlet we added a Check Box type field with the validation script you wrote in the description: "if(currentFieldValue == false){return false;}" and the validation error message: "Tick the checkbox!"
7. Tried to send the created form without selecting the checkbox created in the previous step.

**Result**: "Tick the checkbox!" message appeared on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it like this way but I always got the rrror `You have entered invalid data. Please try again.`.

So I started to change

```
if(currentFieldValue == false){return false;}
```

into

```
if(currentFieldValue != ""){return true;}
```

It seemed that the submit needs an `true` may it's set automaticaly to `false`.

This works with all kind of fields.

Answer (score 0):

The `currentFieldValue` is always a String so the proper solution for me was setting the validation script as follows:

```
return (currentFieldValue == 'true')
```